# NSDateFormatter isn't getting correctly formatted

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have an `NSDateFormatter` I created. I want to print out seconds and milliseconds. Here's my code:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ss\(separator)SSS"    
let string = self.dateFormatter.dateFromString(self.timeLabel.text!) // timeLabel.text = 3:29
println(string!)
```

The `println()` prints out the following:

> 2001-01-01 08:00:03 +000

All I want it to print out, is 3:29. The seconds, and milliseconds. But it prints out different things. How can I get it to print out the seconds and milliseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dateFromString you are converting a string to a date. So, "string" is a date, not a string. And when you print "string" you are printing the value of string's description, with a standard formatter, not using your formatter.

If you want to format a string from the date, use stringFromDate:

Comment: @Jessica, are you invoking stringFromDate with a date? for example, in your previous code, use "string", as it is a date object.

Comment: Right, I just figured that out. Thanks! Gonna accept your answer!